# Unlambda d function

Tags: factorial, promise

I think I need some elaboration on how the D function works in unlambda. Right now I'm trying to make a function (factorial) with the Y combinator, but it always results in some kind of infinite loop. Or segfault, depending on the interpreter. I'm pretty sure D is what I want to use here. I tried this:

````
``d```sii``sii`.xi
````

and it had the same infinite loop. Does anyone think they could help me understand D in unlambda?

...

In unlambda notation, my function is

````
```s``s``s`ks``s`kki``s``s`ks`ki`ki``s``s`ks``s`kki``s``s`ks`ki`ki``s`k`s``s``s``s``si`k`ki`k``s``si`k`ki`kk`k`ki`k`s`sk``s`k`s``s`ksk``s``s`ksk`k``s``si`k``s``s``s``si`ki`k`ki`k`ki`s``s`ksk`k`k`kk

Y= ``s``s``s`ks``s`kki``s``s`ks`ki`ki``s``s`ks``s`kki``s``s`ks`ki`ki

Factorial = Y(\xy.0y1(My(x(Sy))))

0 = ``s``s``si`k`ki`k``s``si`k`ki`kk`k`ki (Returns K if it's 0 in church numerals, Returns KI if it's something else.)

M = ``s`ksk (Prefix multiplier of church numerals)

S = ``s``si`k``s``s``s``si`ki`k`ki`k`ki`s``s`ksk`k`k`kk (Decrements a church integer)
````

I'm pretty sure that if it were evaluated normally, with the left first, it would work, but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's as if that language was specifically designed to mess with Markdown...

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see how `d` could help a factorial function, but an illustration of what `d` does is easy:

```
 `.1` .2i => 21
``.1`d.2i => 12
```

In the first case, `.2` is evaluated before `.1`, on grounds of the eager evaluation rule.

In the second case, `.2` is passed through `.1` "protected", only to be evaluated from the outside.